# От чего зависит цвет уведомления об отсутствии голосов?

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, голосование

Почему уведомление с 1 часом синее, а с 56 минутами красное?

> [image: синий скриншот]

> [image: красный скриншот]

> Вы исчерпали лимит голосований на сегодня; в следующий раз можно будет проголосовать через 52 минуты.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188241

Comment: @alexolut, у них наоборот - большое красное, маленькое - синее. А у нас красное если меньше часа? Странно...

Comment: при пересечении Гринвича знак меняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сообщение после того, как применён последний голос (успешно применён) синее.

При попытке проголосовать ещё раз сверх лимита сообщение красное.

В новом дизайне та же логика:

[image: после применения последнего голоса]

[image: при попытке проголосовать ещё]

Comment: А может, лучше было вопрос отредактировать вместо ответа?